# How to persist when running a mysql on a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-storage

I have a kubernetes cluster with three nodes. I need to deploy a mysql server to the cluster and I need persistence for that mysql. So when I redeploy or restart my pod it won't wipe the data.

But if I use a storageClass which uses azure-disk it will only be mounted to the host.

```
metadata:
  name: mysql-storage
spec:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  storageClassName: "managed-premium"
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 5Gi
```

So if I delete or redeploy the pod it could start up on another host where the disk is not mounted and then my data is gone.

I tried changing the accessModes to ReadWriteMany but that failed when claiming the volume. Saying that it only supported ReadWriteOnce.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really solve this problem. There are several workaround for this problem, like you can create a software storage system on top of managed disks and use that to store data, you can use azure files persistent storage, it can be mounted from any pod (and from many pods).

Managed disks can only be mounted to one node (but I think all the pods on the node can access this disk), So ReadWriteMany doesnt make a lot of sense. You can use [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) to define your mysql, it will always get mounted to the same node, but I dont think you really need it, PVC should get remounted to the node hosting your pod, the only downside is that it takes somewhere around 1 minute to reattach the managed disk to another node.

Comment: Ok it sounds like what I want with the StatefulSets. I can live with the one minute downtime. I won't deploy a new db that often.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) with [PersistentVolumeClaims](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) (PVC).

The following guide gives a nice example on how to do exactly what you want.

[kubernetes.io: Run a Replicated Stateful Application](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/)

In the guide, a few things you need to pay attention:

**StatefulSet** provides guarantees about the ordering and uniqueness of these Pods. And the definition contains a *volumeClaimTemplates*

**volumeClaimTemplates** will ensure each pod gets a *PersistentVolumeClaims* where they can write data.

**PersistentVolumeClaims** reserves the storage and then is later attached\mounted to the POD

Another detail, you should not delete the resources if you want to preserve the data and integrity, you should upgrade.

Comment: Thats a really good link on how to setup a clustered mysql solution.
One thing Im not sure of though. If I use a StatefulSet then I should be guaranteed that the pod always run on the node where they were initially initialised. But if I delete a node then it could start on a different node right?

Comment: As stated in the docs (first link): `StatefulSet Pods have a unique identity that is comprised of an ordinal, a stable network identity, and stable storage. The identity sticks to the Pod, regardless of which node it’s (re)scheduled on.` and for storage `When a Pod is (re)scheduled onto a node, its volumeMounts mount the PersistentVolumes associated with its PersistentVolume Claims`. Given that, PV and PVC should be attached to the POD wherever the POD move to, the issue is that the binding is generally slow, so it might no be a good fit if the POD moves often.

Comment: Perfect. To others who stumble upon this page. On the page [kubernetes.io: Run a Replicated Stateful Application](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/) there is a description on how to test it by draining a node.